# The required type and my provided parameter are different

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I am currently writing code for a scout system I have multiple classes and the hierarchy goes as follows iScoutMember -> Scout(implements iScoutMember) -> `BeaverScout`(extends Scout). I also have a `ScoutList` class that handles adding scouts to the `ArrayList` of scouts and `ScoutSystem` which makes a menu and uses the methods from the `ScoutList` class.

The error I get is from the addScout method in the `ScoutSystem` class when I try to add info for the ArrayList SpecialInterests

This is the error info

**Error:(108, 103) java: incompatible types: SpecialInterest cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<SpecialInterest>**

**Error:(112, 103) java: incompatible types: SpecialInterest cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<SpecialInterest>**

This is the code for the Scout class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public abstract class Scout implements iScoutMember {
private String name;
private String county;
private String dateOfBirth;
private String address;
private String phoneNumber;
private ArrayList<SpecialInterest> specialInterests;

public Scout(String name, String county, String dateOfBirth, String address, String phoneNumber, ArrayList<SpecialInterest> specialInterests) {
    this.name = name;
    this.county = county;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.specialInterests = specialInterests;
}
```

and this is the code for the SpecialInterest class

```
public class SpecialInterest {
private String interestCategory;
private String details;
private String dateBadgeReceived;

public SpecialInterest(String interestCategory, String details, String dateBadgeReceived) {
    this.interestCategory = interestCategory;
    this.details = details;
    this.dateBadgeReceived = dateBadgeReceived;
}
```

and finally this is the code for the addScout method in the Scout system class
    private void addScout(){

```
    System.out.println("What kind of scout would you like to add?.");
    System.out.println("1. Beaver Scout");
    System.out.println("2. Cub Scout");
    System.out.println("3. Scouter");
    int option = input.nextInt();
    switch(option){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Name => ");
            System.out.println("County=> ");
            System.out.println("Date of Birth => ");
            System.out.println("Address => ");
            System.out.println("Contact number => ");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            String county = input.nextLine();
            String dateOfBirth = input.nextLine();
            String address = input.nextLine();
            String phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Special Interest Details");
            System.out.println("Special Interest Category");
            System.out.println("Details");
            System.out.println("date Badge Received");
            String interestCategory = input.nextLine();
            String details = input.nextLine();
            String dateBadgeReceived = input.nextLine();

            SpecialInterest sp1 = new SpecialInterest(interestCategory,details,dateBadgeReceived);

            System.out.println("Do you wish to enter another special Interest: Y/y for yes, N/n for no ==> ");
            String ans = input.nextLine();
            ans.toUpperCase();
            if (ans.equals("Y")){
                System.out.println("Parents Phone Number?");
                String parentPhone = input.nextLine();
                BeaverScout s1 = new BeaverScout(name, county, dateOfBirth, address, phoneNumber, sp1, parentPhone);
                scoutList.addScout(s1);
            } else if(ans.equals("N")){
                String parentPhone = "";
                BeaverScout s1 = new BeaverScout(name, county, dateOfBirth, address, phoneNumber, sp1, parentPhone);
                scoutList.addScout(s1);
            }


    }

}
}
```

This is the line of code that gives me the error

```
BeaverScout s1 = new BeaverScout(name, county, dateOfBirth, address, phoneNumber, sp1, parentPhone);
```

Any and all help will be much appreciated I am completely new to inheritance and to stack overflow so please be patient with me if my question is not formatted properly.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You wrote in your question: _The error I get is from the addScout method in the ScoutSystem class_ You should [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't extremely clear, but from what I can tell, you're passing in a single `SpecialInterest` object (`sp1`) in the addScout method at:

```
SpecialInterest sp1 = new SpecialInterest(interestCategory,details,dateBadgeReceived);
//stuff
BeaverScout s1 = new BeaverScout(name, county, dateOfBirth, address, phoneNumber, sp1, parentPhone);
```

What you probably should do is make a new `ArrayList<SpecialInterest>` and pass *that* in, like this

```
ArrayList<SpecialInterest> sps = new ArrayList<>();
SpecialInterest sp1 = new SpecialInterest(interestCategory,details,dateBadgeReceived);
sps.add(sp1);
//stuff
BeaverScout s1 = new BeaverScout(name, county, dateOfBirth, address, phoneNumber, sps, parentPhone);
```

Comment: I typed in your suggested code instead of my SpecialInterest sp1 = new SpecialInterest(interestCategory,details,dateBadgeReceived);

Comment: Sorry I had accidentally misspelled something in my code it works fine now!